# IIS Deployment issue with several sub projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment, iis-7.5

I am trying to deploy the solution to IIS but it does not work.

I have the following structure in my solution:

- Web ASP.NET MVC project
- Web API project
- Web API project (authentication related)

In the IIS, I created the following structure:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\prj\site

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\prj\api

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\prj\auth
```

IIS has only 1 Web Site, pointing to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\prj\site
That's it. Nothing else.
When I go to localhost/login it displays me the proper page but for some reason authentication does not work, I presume this is because there is something wrong with the settings 
All that works fine when I run the project using VS (Internal IIS), just clicking "run"
Please advise what to check and what to change? Thanks

Comment: Please check if you are using correct address to send auth requests to. Use developers tool in your browser to inspect XHR request you are making from your login form.

Comment: The web site url is localhost, the address it sends requests to is localhost/api/account/login. So it cant see this api, and this is the question what's wrong with the configuration?

Comment: I was able to assign local host with the different ports to each of the site in the project. And locally it works fine, but the web api calls are blocked when I am trying to use the site using the public IP. Is this because of the Cross requests between the sites or what? And is it possible to resolve the issue creating just 1 site in the IIS?

Comment: It could be cross site requests. As I said earlier, use developers tool in browser to see exactly what is the issue. If its CORS related then enable CORS in your web api if you haven't done already. You can also use Postman or fiddler to test your web api methods individually.

Comment: Oh, yes, I used the tools. The request to my API is blocked: blocked:csp. I guess this is because of the cross-calls. But I am not allowed to make changes in the project to allow such kind of the calls. So is it possible to find a way around?

Comment: Then as you have mentioned earlier, keep everything under the same domain name (same site).

Comment: Keeping MVC and Web APIs under the same root folder, marked as Site does not work.

Comment: You need to understand how deployment works on IIS first. Start with some very basic stuff (create an MVC and an API controller with one simple method) and gradually build around simple working app to learn how to do it.